# What set of fields gets returned from .getSObject(fieldName)?

Tags: apex, sobject

I'm working on a function that does a series of `.getSObject()` calls from an Account record to get three fields from one of the related records.

The issue I'm having is one of the fields returns a `SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field` error when doing the .get(), but the other two work fine.

This is what each call looks like, with a different field retrieved each time (account is an Account record that gets passed in):

```
SObject r = account.getSObject('Related1__r');
String test = (String) r.getSObject('Related2__r').get('fieldName__c');
```

It's not clear from Salesforce documentation what the object returned from `.getSObject()` and why it works fine for two fields but fails for the third. I can do a dynamic SOQL query to retrieve the same record that should be returned from the `Related2__r` `.getSObject()` call and then do a `.get()` on the exact same field but when I try to do the code snippet above for that particular field, it fails. It seems as if the `.getSObject()` only retrieves a subset of the fields, and in my case it doesn't include the field I need.

Comment: It should depend on which fields you're querying (as the error may suggest). What does your query look like? and what are the actual field/relationship names here?

Comment: But what query? On the original Account object way up the chain? How does that determine what fields get retrieved from the related records? Sorry I am fairly new to SFDX. The actual names are custom, not OOTB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getSObject` method returns all fields in memory. The following two lines should function identically:

```
SObject related = account.Related2__r;
// or
SObject related = account.getSObject('Related2__r');
```

If you are getting the error:

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field

It means your SOQL does not include `Related2__r.RequestedField__c`. Double check your top level `SELECT` clause. Every field included in the below `SELECT` clause would carry over:

```
SELECT
    Related2__r.Field1__c,
    Related2__r.Field2__c,
    Related2__r.Field3__c
FROM Account
```

However, if you tried to reference `Related2__r.Field4__c`, you would encounter this error.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to dynamically include other fields, or will I need to amend the original query?

Comment: The query needs to include any fields you de-reference.

Comment: Are the two lines in your first snippet equivalent in turns of performance as well? I.e. is one going to perform slower than the other, or does one count against any of the limiters?